# ORACLE: Query a column (type TIMESTAMP) of a table

Tags: oracle11g, timestamp

I want to query a table that has one column has timestamp as its datatype.

I want to query this table with that particular column with the value of lets say 17:00. How can i do that.

At this moment, I have this syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName = '17:00';
```

I have spent some time, but cannot figure out how to write the syntax.

Comment: A `TIMESTAMP` contains a day and a time with sub-second precision.  Are you looking for rows where the `TIMESTAMP` represents March 14, 2013 at 17:00:00.000000000?  Are you looking for rows that are between March 14, 2013 17:00:00.000000000 and March 14, 2013 17:00:59.999999999?  Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I am just looking for the the 17:00 time, date and other things don't matter., is that something can be done?

Comment: So you want data from any day where the time is exactly 17:00:00.000000000?  Or are you looking for a range of times?

Comment: yes, I want data from any day where the time is exactly 17:00. Not the range of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want data from any day where the time is exactly 17:00:00.000000000

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableName
 WHERE EXTRACT( hour FROM columnName ) = 17
   AND EXTRACT( minute FROM columnName ) = 0
   AND EXTRACT( second FROM columnName ) = 0
```

If you are populating this column by getting the current timestamp (which is the most common approach), I wouldn't expect that this would find anything.  It is exceptionally unlikely that the current time would be 5pm to the millisecond or microsecond (or nanosecond) depending on the platform generating the timestamp.

Comment: @user1889838 - If you are populating the column by getting the current timestamp, looking for a range of values is probably what you want, yes.  You may be populating it from some other source, though, in which case it may make sense to look for a specific value (if, for example, after-hours actions are always logged as happening at precisely 17:00:00.000000000).  It's odd to ignore the day component as well but I assume you have a valid reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you too

```
 select * from schema2.time_stamp_test  t  where t.in_time like '%17:00:00%';

--in_time column_name
```